# why can't i fill the map with map.put, android

Tags: android, dictionary

I have the map declared before onCreate

```
    public ArrayList<Map<String,String>> c_tmp= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    public Map<String,String> mapa;
```

and then in a function that is triggered by textwatcher, I want to fill the map but there seems to be an error

```
    String numberz = phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
              if(numberz.contains("07"))
  {  name1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                       if(name1!=null)
                                    {
                                           nnn=name1;//+"\n"+numberz;
                                         mapa.put(numberz,nnn);
                                        c_tmp.add(mapa);
                                    } 
                               }
```

Comment: Need more info like stack trace. Could be as simple as the type of map does not allow null.

Comment: Did you define mapa? (mapa = new Map<String, String>())

Comment: "An error"? Why wouldn't you say what the error is?! Where's `mapa` defined?

Comment: because i don't know the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line :

```
mapa.put(numberz,nnn);
```

will throw an error. mapa is not instanciated in your code.

replace the second line by :

```
public Map<String,String> mapa = new Map<String,String>();
```

Comment: it says cannot initiate Map<string,string> when i am trying to do ur code

Comment: It should be public Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: here where the code stucks now  when it's trying  to do initialize name_val
 name_Val = (String[]) c_tmp.toArray(new String[c_tmp.size()]);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,name_Val);
   txtPhoneName.setAdapter(adapter);